# Change name of input within specific table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using a function which I've adapted to clone table rows when a certain button is clicked (see [this](https://jsfiddle.net/kXmpY/1/) fiddle), and assign the new row an incremented ID (i.e. `table-rows-1` to `table-rows-2`). After creating a new row, I want a function I'm making to find an input in a td in this row and change its name from `input-text-1` to `input-text-2`. I'm not very confident with Javascript, and am having trouble accessing the input element within the row. Heres an example:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="modal-rows" id="table-rows-1">
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="input-text" name="input-text-1">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="modal-rows" id="table-rows-2">   <<< DUPLICATED ROW WITH INCREMENT ID
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="input-text" name="input-text-1">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

How can I access the inner inputs of this table in order to change their name? Heres what I've tried:

```
var rowNum = document.getElementsByClassName("modal-rows").length

$('#table-rows-' + rowNum + ' .input-text').attr('name', 'input-text-' + rowNum);
$('#table-rows-' + rowNum).find('.input-text').attr('name', 'input-text-' + rowNum);
$('#table-rows-' + rowNum).children('.input-text').attr('name', 'input-text-' + rowNum);
```

Can anyone let me know where I'm going wrong?

Comment: This: $('#table-rows-' + rowNum).find('.input-text').attr('name', 'input-text-' + rowNum); looks fine to me.

Comment: If that is the code that you are using, what exactly isn't working because nothing obvious is wrong with your code. So it might be something else in your code.

Comment: The fiddle you've linked to doesn't show something duplicating table rows

Comment: Through comments, the question has changed since it's original version.  The OP needs to confirm that it still is not working.

Comment: Thanks @HaukarHalf, turns out I had a syntax error in this line of code and that's why it didn't work. Thanks to everyone else for helping.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code inside your duplicate function:
clone.children[0].setAttribute('name', 'input-text'+ ++i)